# sub-type of time.Time doesn't create the Column using gorm lib

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to add a timestamp to the database and have the returned json with the number representing the timestamp instead of the current string representation of timestamp; essentially overriding marshal,unmarshal of `time.Time`

```
type JSONTime time.Time

func (j *JSONTime) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if string(data) == "null" {
        return nil
    }
    millis, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(data), 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *j = JSONTime(time.Unix(0, millis*int64(time.Millisecond)))
    return err
}

func (t JSONTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    //do your serializing here
    stamp := fmt.Sprintf("%d", time.Time(t).Unix()*1000)
    return []byte(stamp), nil
}
type table struct {
    ID        int64    `gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment"json:"id"`
    CreatedAt JSONTime json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt JSONTime json:"updatedAt"`
}
```

the problem I have the above code simply ignores the creation of the columns on my database (other fields are created). I even manually created the column but gorm doesn't add the data either.

I believe marshal and unmarshal work, but problem lies before even using them (i.e. adding the columns to db)

what do am I doing wrong here?

I'm using [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) and library [gorm](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm)

**UPDATE 1:**

Previously I had my table structure as follows:

```
type table struct {
    ID        int64    `gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment"json:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time json:"updatedAt"`
}
```

this was mostly working (e.g. creating columns on the database)

in terms of database connection, I basically used:

```
root:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/database?parseTime=true
```

and use auto migrate for my repo:

```
db,err := // get db connection 
if err != nil {
    panic("Failed to connect to database")
}
db.AutoMigrate(&table{})
```

Comment: Try implementing the `sql.Scanner` and the `driver.Valuer` interfaces for your custom type.

Comment: If that by itself doesn't help make sure to add `gorm` tags to the `JSONTime` fields. And please fix the rest of the tags, it is hard to know whether or not your actual code has the same tag mess as in the question, or whether you were just careless writing out the question.

Comment: none of this code performs a migration, so from here, it wont create ANY colums ANYway. You **must** provide a simple, minimal, reproducible example of the sequence of code that you have been able to identify within your code base as not working so that we can help you.

Comment: Just clarifying something. What datatypes are the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields in the table schema?

If you are using `datetime` then you can scan the column directly into `time.Time` as long as you use `?parseTime=true` when you open the db connection.

Comment: @mkopriva I've updated the question hopefully that suffice

Comment: @mkopriva actually as you said I think I need to implement driver.Valuer interface. https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Value says driver only supports some basic types (e.g. int64,time.Time, etc)

Comment: @nafas the tags are still a mess, there needs to be space between different tags. You're missing one `\`` in your tags, and you have a duplicate `createdAt` tag.

Comment: @nafas and yes, do implement the Valuer interface but also the Scanner interface. While I don't know what gorm does underneath, the standard library, which is used by gorm, does not recognize the `JSONTime` type and will not be able to store or read it from the database without the Value and Scan methods.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for pointing out, it was mostly typo when I moved to stackoverflow. I'll try to implement Valuer and Scanner. will update later

Comment: @mkopriva hey dude, took a while but finally managed to figure it out. thanks for your pointers. would be great if I get ur opinion on the answer, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @mkopriva, I finally figured it out.

There were a few issues:

1- `MarshalJSONand` `UnmarshalJSON` are only for before and after database interaction

2- the structure `table` definition didn't have the right `gorm` definition:

```
type tablestruct {
    ID        int64            `gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment"json:"id"`
    CreatedAt timeLib.JSONTime `gorm:"type:timestamp;default:current_timestamp"json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt timeLib.JSONTime `gorm:"type:timestamp;default:current_timestamp ON update current_timestamp"json:"updatedAt"`
}
```

3- since type `JSONTime` is a new type, driver doesn't know how to convert it, so we need to override `Value`:

```
func (jsonTime JSONTime) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return time.Time(jsonTime), nil
}
```

4- finally we need to override `Scan` in order to convert database value into `JSONTime` value

```
func (jsonTime *JSONTime) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    if value == nil {
        *jsonTime = JSONTime(time.Now())
        return nil
    }
    if readTime, err := driver.DefaultParameterConverter.ConvertValue(value); err == nil {
        if convertedTime, ok := readTime.(time.Time); ok {
            *jsonTime = JSONTime(convertedTime)
            return nil
        }
    }
    return errors.New("failed to scan TIME")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
type JSONTime struct {
    time.Time
}

type BaseModel struct {
    ID        uint     `gorm:"autoIncrement;primary_key" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt JSONTime `gorm:"type:timestamp;default:current_timestamp" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt JSONTime `gorm:"type:timestamp;default:current_timestamp" json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt JSONTime `gorm:"type:timestamp;default:current_timestamp" json:"deleted_at"`
}
```